# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, filter

I wanted to filter the list of books depending on the clicked author on the left. the authors and the books are in separate arrays, so I got the author id when clicking with route.params and trying to filter books depending on that id but it gives me an error.

How should I filter books on the right with the clicked author??

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BooksService } from '../shared/books.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Book } from './book.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-books',
  templateUrl: './books.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./books.component.scss']
})
export class BooksComponent implements OnInit {
  books: Book[];
  filteredBooks: Book[];
  id: string;

  constructor(
    private booksService: BooksService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}



  ngOnInit() {
    this.booksService.booksChanged
    .subscribe(
      (books: Book[]) => {
        this.books = books;
      }
    );
    this.books = this.booksService.getBooks();

    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.id = params['id'];
      this.filteredBooks = this.booksService.books.filter(item => item.author === this.id);
      console.log(this.filteredBooks);
    });
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use **subscribe** for the method which returns books:

```
this.booksService.getBooks().subscribe(books => {
  this.filteredBooks = books.filter(item => item.author === this.id);
});
```

Comment: It works onit but not on click, Means when change author doesnt change books

Comment: Have you used this.booksService.getBooks().subscribe() inside this.route.params.subscribe()?

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter from **`this.books`** not from **`this.booksService.books`**

```
 this.filteredBooks = this.books.filter(item => item.author === this.id);
```

Comment: It still gives me ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Comment: @AhmedShaarawy, set variable like this `books: Book[] = [];`  instead of  `books: Book[];` this..

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused when the incoming data is 'null' and the filter method was expecting data, thus, this caused the error.

1) Try checking if the data exists
or
2) you could initially provide an empty array. Not sure if this works though

```
books: Book[] = [];
```

Can you see if this works?

Comment: You were right but I made if condition so it works now, Thanks.

Comment: @AhmedShaarawy glad you fixed it!